# Java Comparable interface trouble

Tags: java, compare

So I've a program that numerically sorts out an array list with a string and a double. I have to also have the array be sorted out by alphabetical order without tempering with the BankAccount class that contains the compareTo code.

I can only modify the compare infertace which is contained in the JavaCollections class. I keep thinking that it has something to do with the printout, but I'm unsure.

Here's the code for the BankAccount class:

```
import java.util.Collections;

public class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount>{
    private double balance;
    private String owner;

    public BankAccount(String owner, double balance) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return owner;
    }

    /**
    Compares two bank accounts.
    @param other the other BankAccount
    @return 1 if this bank account has a greater balance than the other,
     -1 if this bank account is has a smaller balance than the other one,
     and 0 if both bank accounts have the same balance
    */
    public int compareTo(BankAccount other) {
        if(balance > other.balance) {
            return 1;
        } else if (balance < other.balance) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the code for the JavaCollections class which I can modify:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JavaCollections extends BankAccount{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Put bank accounts into a list 
        ArrayList<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<BankAccount>(); 
        BankAccount ba1 = new BankAccount ("Bob", 1000);
        BankAccount ba2 = new BankAccount ("Alice", 101);
        BankAccount ba3 = new BankAccount ("Tom", 678);
        BankAccount ba4 = new BankAccount ("Ted", 1100);
        BankAccount ba5 = new BankAccount ("Tom", 256);

        list.add(ba1); 
        list.add(ba2); 
        list.add(ba3); 
        list.add(ba4);
        list.add(ba5); 

        // Call the library sort method
        Collections.sort(list);

        // Print out the sorted list 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            BankAccount b = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(b.getName() + ": $" + b.getBalance()); 
        }   
    }

    public JavaCollections(String owner, double balance) {
        super(owner, balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this code printing. ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom `Comparator` class that compares two `BankAccount` objects using their name.

```
class AccountComparator implements Comparator<BankAccount> {

    @Override
    public int compare(BankAccount o1, BankAccount o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }

}
```

Then when sorting the list, use an instance of this custom `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(list, new AccountComparator());
```

Or even easier e.g. when you need to do it only once:

```
list.sort((a,b) -> a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()));
```